# Embedding Elasticsearch in Desktop Application

Tags: c++, elasticsearch, search, text, desktop-application

I'm developing a C++ desktop application and want to have complete set of search capabilities like stemming, customized ranking algorithm, etc for some huge text content.

previously I used ElasticSearch in some web applications. but is it possible to embed ElasticSearch in a desktop application and make the client machine as a server machine?
Is there any end well experience?

If no so what is the better option for having advance search system in desktop application?

Answer (score 2):

There appear to be two c++ ports of the Lucene library which Elasticsearch is based upon.

Assuming that you require the search and indexing functionality of ElasticSearch rather than the sharding, replication and redundancy parts of it.

http://clucene.sourceforge.net/

https://github.com/luceneplusplus/LucenePlusPlus

Neither library seems to have been updated particularly recently though